# SQL - join statements puzzle

Tags: sql

Puzzle here!

I got a table named `whitelist`, a table named `bans`.
Each user is identified by an identifier.
Users could be :

- not banned, not whitelisted.
- banned, not whitelisted.
- not banned, whitelisted.
- banned, whitelisted.

If a user if banned, a line is created in bans table.
If a user is whitelisted, a line is created in whitelisted table.

I have this acual SQL statement for checking if the user is banned or whitelisted:
`SELECT * FROM whitelist FULL JOIN bans ON bans.identifier=whitelist.id`.

The issue is: if the user isn't whitelisted, `whitelist.id` doesn't exist (obviously). But how to treat all the case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is right, I missed. I remove this, thanks for your comment

Comment: How about `SELECT (bans.id_user IS NOT NULL) AS banned, (whitelist.id_user IS NOT NULL) AS whitelisted FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN bans ON bans.id_user = u.id LEFT JOIN whitelist ON whitelist.id_user = u.id`? Sorry for not using Your exact columns names.

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want to know each of those 4 bullets, or do you just want a list of users that appear in either table?

Comment: @dfundako a list user, I'll be more specific next time.
RomanHocke That's what I was searching, thanks, I'll test  this

Comment: You say a user can't be whitelisted and banned, but do you actually have logic/safeguards to prevent this case?

Comment: So what RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make the assumption that you have a users table. Depending on your RDBMS, you can use exists or joins. This will allow you to check if a user record exists in either bans or whitelists.

Use exists to check if that user appears in either table:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM user u
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM whitelist wl
ON wl.userID = u.userid)
OR EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM ban b
WHERE b.userid = u.userID)
```

Or you can use joins and check for NULLS and then conditionally change the NULL to be a 1 or 0, yes or no, etc.:

```
SELECT u.*, wl.userID, b.userID 
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN whitelist wl
ON wl.userID = u.userID
LEFT JOIN ban b
ON b.userID = u.userid
WHERE wl.userID IS NOT NULL
or b.userID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need logic to combine them:

```
select coalesce(b.identifier, w.id) as id,
       (case when b.identifier is not null and w.identifier is not null then 'both'
             when b.identifier is not null then 'ban'
             else 'whitelist'
        end) as which
from bans b full join
     whitelist w
     on b.identifier = w.id  -- why do these have different names
```

Comment: They have different name because my sql connector says : `ambigous column identifier` otherway...
Thanks I'll make some testing

Comment: @Izio . . . This doesn't do what you want?